# What physically/chemically happens to a vegetable when it is cooked?

Tags: vegetables, food-science

I've discovered that if I eat raw vegetables, I can't digest them well if at all. If I steam, boil, nuke, bake, grill, or otherwise cook the vegetables, I feel fine.

What are the physical/chemical differences after cooking, especially those that assist in digestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is the degradation of cell walls. The human digestive system does indeed struggle to break down the cellulose in cell walls, meaning that we are far more efficient in getting nutrients from vegetables when they are cooked.

That doesn't mean however that cooked veggies are ***always*** more nutritious than raw ones. There is actually quite a bit of debate on that and some people even eat raw foods exclusively.

Your question is actually very similar to [this earlier question on this site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18047/what-are-ways-to-reduce-cellulose-in-vegetables-and-fruits). You might find some useful insights there.